# In Jetpack Compose, what can you do to make the top bar title track which screen you're on when using Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I want to use Compose navigation with my top bar and bottom bar in my scaffold. My bottom bar items are the "main" screens, while they each have other screens that they can branch out to.

I want to be able to have my top bar title update every time a new screen appears.

What is the best way to have the top bar keep track with what screen you're on?

Comment: I have written an article on how to make ```BottomNavigation``` with changing title on ```TopAppBar```. you can read it. https://medium.com/@chiragthummar16/jetpack-compose-bottom-navigation-with-scaffold-material3-717e28ccc811

Comment: @ChiragThummar Thanks! Would this work if you're navigate to an inner/child screen? For example, if bottom navigation shows screen A, B, C, would the title also change if we go to screen A2, A3, B2?

Comment: It will work only for bottom navigation. you need to add one more function to make it as per your choice